# Return OAuthGrantClientCredentialsContext with ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following jquery code that returns a token from my web api:

```
var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "http://localhost:51734/token",
    "method": "POST",
    "data": {
        grant_type: "client_credentials",
        client_id: "6E1JIQDEF0M"
    }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

This works very well. I get a object with my access token.

However, If I run the same code again, I should get a error-object that says that an token already has been issued.

I do that here in my C#-code:

```
 public override async Task GrantClientCredentials(OAuthGrantClientCredentialsContext context)
        {
            //Prevent the user to issue a new token
            var existingRefreshToken = await _authService.FindRefreshTokenByClientId(context.ClientId);

            if (existingRefreshToken != null)
            {
                context.SetError("client_authentication", "The client already have an issued access token");
                return;
            }
}
```

But I only get this error in the console: `Cors header 'access-control-allow-origin' is missing`

I have enabled CORS in the webapi. So why do I get this error when I try to access It again?

Comment: Don't you need context.Rejected(); after context.SetError?

Comment: @zuckerburg: Nah, because It works as expected in Postman :)

Comment: No worries, my experience with Postman is that "what works in postman doesn't always work in practice"